# Elixir URI.encode_query nested map

Tags: elixir

Elixir `URI.encode_query` works well on not-nested maps, like:

```
URI.encode_query(%{ a: "b", c: "d" }) # => "a=b&c=d"
```

But if I try to encode nested map, like

```
URI.encode_query(%{ a: %{ b: "c" } })
```

I get

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for %{b: "c"}
```

How could I encode query with nested map in it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Elixir's `URI` module does not support nested maps but you can use the `plug` package's `Plug.Conn.Query.encode/1` which does support nested maps:

```
iex(1)> Plug.Conn.Query.encode %{ a: "b", c: "d" }
"a=b&c=d"
iex(2)> Plug.Conn.Query.encode %{ a: %{ b: "c" } }
"a[b]=c"
```